# Change css JQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to change css of class in my HTML.
I'm struggling with that already a long time, and I'm not getting what i'm doing wrong. (I've tried already many versions, but nothing happends)

For example: I would like to change the row height on this following html:

game.html

```
<div class="game">
<ul class="each" data-bind="foreach: {data: rows, as: 'row'}">
    <li class = "li">
        <ul class="row" data-bind="foreach: {data: row.beads, as: 'bead'}">
            <li class="bead" data-bind="
            currentSide: left,
            drag: bead.drag.bind(bead),
            ></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

app.css

```
.row {position: relative;
max-width: 3000px;}
```

game.html

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var windowHeight = $( window ).height();
    var rowHeight = windowHeight/5;
    $('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="bead" data-bind="
            currentSide: left,
            drag: bead.drag.bind(bead)">//Missing closing ", Avoided extra ,
```

And

```
$('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight + "px");//Add `px`
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9knXh/18/)

Comment: No, just nothing change.
On element property i still see 3000 as it was on default

Comment: @~Lorenz_i Do you want to change the row height or width? If height see my answer, you have an error

Comment: Have included the demo fiddle.

Comment: I'm getting the allert, but nothing really happend on my page.

48 hours already on that!

Comment: Not. i tryied to copy the example as is from fiddle, still didn't work. i see the hello for all screen width

it is not my index.html, its game.html does it matter for some reason?

Comment: no it won't effect, try to create a separate HTML and paste the code as it is from fiddle. Hope some thing else going wrong some where

Comment: Still didn't work. 
The html is on seperate file in any case, and I also tried to delete css file. I'm calling the page from shell, with line:
<div>
    <div id="shell" data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }"/>
</div>

Comment: Also i tried to put it directly on index.html body, but it's still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var windowHeight = $( window ).height();
    var rowHeight = windowHeight/5;
   $('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight + 'px');
});
```

This oughta do it.!!!

You have to append px:

> $('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight + 'px');

Comment: Same thing happened to me ,my 1st time..
Glad that a friend was there to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work: `$('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight);`

This will: `$('.row').css({maxWidth: rowHeight + 'px'});`

Comment: `$('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight + 'px')` will also work. Instead, `$('.row').css({maxWidth: rowHeight + 'px'})` will not work, as maxWidth is not a css property.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing:

```
$('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight); // outputs 100
```

You have to append `px`:

```
$('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight + 'px'); // outputs 100px
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the height of the row

```
$('.row').css('max-width', rowHeight);
```

Needs to be

```
$('.row').css('max-height', rowHeight + 'px');
```

You need to append the **px** to the value and change **max-width** to **max-height**

And you need to change this typo: -

```
drag: bead.drag.bind(bead),
```

To: -

```
drag: bead.drag.bind(bead)"
```

Comment: I want to change both of them :) this doesn't work for me for any reason! so annoying! Seems that no matter which change I'm doing, i don't see  it on element properties after running the script.